# Private key not found

Tags: apache2, security, ssl

I have tried to generate server certificate for apache2 earlier....

I have noticed one error in apache server. Which means that Apache can't find the private key component of new SSL certificate. Now I want to remove the server certificate.

#### Command:

```
root@wiffyspot1:#  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                             Action 'start' failed.
```

#### I have check the Apache error log:

```
[error] Init: Private key not found
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 14 11:00:50 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the config files/virtualhosts that you modified?

Comment: i have no access for virtualhosts config file because it is located on cloud. I recalled that I have just run below commends with some RnD to populated the error. # apt-get install ssl-cert
# mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
# /usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert /usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
# a2enmod ssl && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Check the `default-ssl` file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available
`

Comment: I was trying to post the default-ssl but it was too long. I am writing here some content of it.                 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost..............SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
...........